# Android JNI Using Pre built .so file in C Code

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am trying my hand at Android JNI. 
So far I have just written the basic Hello World Android JNI App. 
Now I was thinking if it would be possible to build a .so file seperately. Then use that library in my JNI Layer C Code.

So basically I want to build a libsample.so using command line gcc in windows. Then use this .so file in the JNI I write for my android app. 
So far from my understanding I should be able to do this by editing the Android.mk file.

But what would those edits be ?

EDIT: Source code attached.

jnitest.cpp -

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "specialPrint.h"

extern "C" jstring Java_com_example_hwjni_MainActivity_helloFromJni(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    return env->NewStringUTF(SpecialPrint("This is external .so talking."));
}
```

specialPrint.h -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
char* SpecialPrint(char* s);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

specialPrint.c -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "specialPrint.h"

char* SpecialPrint(char* s) {
    return s;
}
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := MyPrebuiltLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = specialPrint.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := jnitest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jnitest.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := MyPrebuiltLib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

P.S. - Although right now I am trying to do this with the source. But eventually I really need to do this stuff without the source of specialPrint. If you could help me achive that then it would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: declare a prebuilt library as module
Step 2: refer the prebuilt module as local shared library

for example

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := MyPrebuiltLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = path/to/libSuper.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := DroidJNILib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := AwsomeCode.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := MyPrebuiltLib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

If you have the source

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := MyPrebuiltLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES =mysource.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := DroidJNILib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := AwsomeCode.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := MyPrebuiltLib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I got this error: D:/android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip:./libs/armeabi/speciallib.so: File format not recognized

Comment: are you sure speciallib.so is for arm arch?

Comment: no actually.. i m nt sure about that either.. I used gcc to create the so file using gcc -shared command. Any more arguments I need to pass to get .so file for arm arch?

Comment: if u have a *nix enviroment you can command "file" to see what is arch, i think it should work on cyqwin as well.

Comment: if did with simple gcc it wont be an arm library most probably it will be of i386 ( depends on ur pc) . u need to compile it using arm toolchain, if u have the source u can compile it in using andoid.mk very easily

Comment: now i m getting undefined reference to a function which is in the MyPrebuiltLib when i call it from DroidJNILib.

Comment: you need to include the header files

Comment: the error is because ur mixing c and cpp, u need to wrap ur c declaration in extern c  change ur header to     
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
char* SpecialPrint(char* s);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif